# Quantum Hall Effect: Two-terminal resistance and thermodynamic equilibrium

Tags: condensed-matter, equilibrium, quantum-hall-effect, chemical-potential

In [Goerbig's lecture notes on the quantum hall effect](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1998), Fig. 3.3 describes the so-called two-terminal measurement. The figure and accompanying text show us that in a two-terminal measurement, the measured resistance across the terminals is in fact the Hall resistance. This relies upon the fact that the upper edge is at the same chemical potential as the left contact, while the lower edge is at the same chemical potential as the right contact. Why is the previous sentence true?

Goerbig says that it's because the top edge is at thermodynamic equilibrium with the left contact and the bottom edge is at thermodynamic equilibrium with the right contact. What prevents the left contact from talking to the bottom edge? It seems like the bottom edge could inject electrons into the left contact and thus modify the equilibrium that exists between the left contact + top edge. I don't understand why just because the top edge takes electrons away from the left contact, that implies the equilibrium is between that pair.

Thanks to anyone out there for their help!!

[image]

Comment: In absence of scattering, clearly the top edge can take electron only from the left contact, so one should expect the distribution function for top edge to be completely contained in the distribution function for the left contact, which is so large that its distribution function cannot alter if one or two electron come or go per unit time. However, this is only true in the absence of scattering. In presence of scattering, this is no longer true, and top edge distribution function indeed takes contribution from both contacts. For details, see Ch2 (Section 2.3) of Mesoscopic Transport by S Datta